# Get push notification data when application is in background IOS

Tags: ios, push-notification

Hi I am developing small IOS application in which I am using push notification. So in my case I am able get notifications and I am also able to access data for notification. Data from notification mean title, description etc. So in my case I am not saving my notification at my server side. I want to save those locally. For that what I want as soon as notification come I want to save that data locally. I am able to access my data when App is in foreground but I am not able to access my notification data when app is in background. I want to access the data of notification so that I can save it. For notification I did following things:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

return YES;
}

 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken {
 }

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
 didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
for (NSString *key in [userInfo allKeys])
{
    NSString *data = [userInfo objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"inside did register for notification .... %@  ---- > %@",key,data);
}
}
```

My requirement is simple I want access to notification when my app is in background. Any one is here who already did this? Need Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS, the app cannot access it's push notification until the user taps on the push notification from the notification center.
Once the push notification is tapped and the app loads/becomes active, only then will you be able to access the push notification.

FYI:

1. When the app is in background and a push notification is recieved.
   After the user taps on the push notification:

   - the contents will be accessible in the `-didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method.
2. When the app is not open and a push notification is received.
   After the user taps on the push notification

   - the contents will be accessible in the `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in it's `launchOptions` parameter.

Also... push notifications aren't 100% reliable. They may or may not be delivered (although them not being delivered is pretty rare in my observation but worth pointing out none-the-less)

Comment: Ohhh Is that really true? Dam bad. But why they are not allowing. Is there any other bypass for this ?

Comment: @nilkash : **[1]** yes, that's true (afaik) and **[2]** i think they're not allowed due to, *maybe*, **performance** issues because if multiple apps get push notifications and they each do their own thing then the device performance will take a major hit. Also maybe security reasons... who knows. **[3]** i don't know of any way to bypass this.

Comment: hi staticVoidMan thank you for your quick replay. I just tested what you said. only thing is that when I click on my notification it launched my application and also execute -didReceiveRemoteNotification method. Then why we have to access it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: I am not accepting your answer because I am waiting for my problem answer but your answer is also gives good idea.Thank you.

Comment: @nilkash : two scenarios: **first**... your app is closed (*like totally closed i.e not in your currently running apps list*) then the push notification is accessible in the `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. **second**... your app is running (_but in background_). Now the push notification is accessible in the `-didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method. **Do one thing: quit your app, send a push notification and try to access it.**

Comment: yeah sure let me try this as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in iOS 7.0 and later where you can send notifications and access its content without user tapping it.
So, the notification payload which you send has a parameter called **content-available**. You can view the payload parmeters in the following link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

So when you set the **content available** to **1** and deliver the notification, iOS calls the below function even if the app is not in the background or foreground(must have remote notification enabled)

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

Then you can use the userInfo dictionary to fetch your notification data.